# Используя вложенный list comprehension, сформировать двумерный список

Tags: python

Используя вложенный list comprehension, сформируйте двумерный список, представляющий следующую квадратную таблицу чисел размером 4 х 4: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 Результат выведите на экран.

То есть чтобы был формат:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4][5, 6, 7, 8]и тд.]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ list(range(i * 4 + 1, (i + 1) * 4 + 1)) for i in range(4) ]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

```
[[i, i+1, i+2, i+3] for i in range(1,4*4,4)]
```

или

```
[list(range(i, i+4)) for i in range(1,4*4,4)]
```

или

```
[[j for j in range(i, i+4)] for i in range(1,4*4,4)]
```

или

```
[[j+i*4 for j in r] for i,r in enumerate([[1,2,3,4]]*4)]
```